# How to display a member from the list in Dictionary<int, List<string>>?

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` where the key is a paper code and the list is a list of students enrolled in the paper.

How do i display this list of students from a particular key ?

I have tried

`Console.WriteLine(myDictionary[targetkey])`

but i just get this back

`System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]`

Answer (score 1):

`myDictionary[targetkey]` will return the `List<string>` at the given key and if you pass that to `Console.WriteLine`, it will just call `.ToString()` on it which will return `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]`. Actually any object you pass to `Console.WriteLine` method, it will call `ToString()` on it.

If youYou need to iterate over your dictionary and then print each one out.

```
foreach(var thisList in myDictionary.Keys)
{
    foreach(var thisStudent in thisList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(thisStudent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TryGetValue` to make sure the key is there.  Then just loop through your `List<string>`.

```
var targetKey = 123;
List<string> students;

if(dictionary.TryGetValue(targetKey, out students))
    foreach(var student in students)
        Console.WriteLine(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use for loop,

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> dicItem in test)
{
   foreach (string entry in dicItem.Value)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Current entry for list {0}: {1}", dicItem.Key, entry);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
foreach ( var student in myDictionary[targetKey])
{
  Console.WriteLine(student);
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are frowned upon in SO. Please add some explanation for the benefit of others reading your code!

Answer (score 0):

`myDictionary[targetkey]` returns `List<String>` so Covert `List<String>` to `string Array`

Print result like below

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(targetkey))
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myDictionary[targetkey].ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solutions

```
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    List<string> students = new List<string>();
    //adding Elements to list
    students.Add("Raees Ul Islam");
    students.Add("Ubaid Ur Rehman");
    //adding item to dictionary
    dictionary.Add(1, students);
    //Retriveing Data from Dictionary..
    Console.WriteLine(((List<string>)dictionary[1])[0]);
    Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    //An Other Way to go through All Elements
    List<string> studentsRetrived = dictionary[1];

    foreach (var item in studentsRetrived)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```